# ImageButton (right-aligned, fixed width) and EditText (left-aligned, remaining space width)

Tags: android, android-layout, right-align

I'm trying to put, in the same row, an `ImageButton` (right align, fixed width) and an `EditText` (left align, taken up all the remaining space), but I can't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditText
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="EditText"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't use the property `"layout_weight"` because I want to fix the width of the `ImageButton`. If I use `"layout_width=fill_parent"` in the `EditText`, the `ImageButton` disappears.

Could you help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="EditText"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Just i change layout_width of EditText fill_parent to 0dp and set layout_weight="1", so it will stretched and take remaining space.

[Check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) for LinearLayout weight concept.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Yes, the `android:layout_weight="1" />` works perfectly. I misunderstood the use of the layout_weight property. I thought that you have to specify this property for all the views in the same layout, but now I know that you can use it only in the views you want to affect.

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `layout_weight`, use `RelativeLayout`. In the `RelativeLayout` first put the `ImageButton` and align it to right of RelativeLayout. Then put the `EditText` with `layout_width="fill_parent"` place it to left of `ImageButton`

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/id_image_button"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/id_image_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?:

```
<EditText
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:text="EditText"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Yes, the `android:layout_weight="1" />` works perfectly. I misunderstood the use of the layout_weight property. I thought that you have to specify this property for all the views in the same layout, but now I know that you can use it only in the views you want to affect.

Thanks again!!